# Recyclerview 2 Different Layouts

Tags: android, android-studio

So I'm making an application that has 2 different layouts inside a only one RecyclerView.
I can do that, but my problem is,
I want to set the size of "A"(Please look at the pic below) to take 70% of screen size.
And "B" to take 30% of the screen.
I Know how to work with weight_sum/layout_weight but I can't think of anything
that will work for this.

[image]

Comment: why do you need a recyclerview if there are only 2 items in total?

Comment: No. The letter A is a Map, And letter "B" consists of lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `screen height` in that case and pass it to your `recyclerview adapter`.

Use `getItemViewType()` for two different layouts.

and in `OnCreateViewHolder()` while creating view set `heights` to `view` as per your requirements. It will work.

Comment: Okay ill try it

Comment: @CharlesGalvez Glad to here :)